# Method of Solving Non-Linear simultaneous equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, problem-solving, nonlinear-system

I have been stumped on this particular question wherein we have an equation of a circle and equation of a hyperbola and it needs to be solved via elimination method. Solving the question graphically is quite easy, however the algebraic solution has stumped me

$x^2+y^2-3x=9$;
$x^2-y^2+x+4y=3$

Above are the system of non- linear equations.

Comment: How many solutions are you getting when you're solving it geometrically?

Comment: 3 solutions x=0,y=3;x=1-2√2 ,y=√2 -1;x=1+2√2 ,y=-1-2√2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint...you can eliminate $x^2$ by subtracting these and get $x$ in terms of $y$.

Substitute this into the first equation and get a quartic in $y$, namely

$$y^4-4y^3-4y^2+24y-9=0$$ which is readily solvable.